# How can I enable drag and drop of images/labels

Tags: python, image, drag-and-drop, pyqt4

I am using python 3.4 and PyQt4.
I have the following problem: I want to create a program in which a marble should be clicked on and dragged from one glass and dropped into another glass (see picture below):

[image: Picture of the idea (arrow is not included in actual program)]

I know that the `QPushButton` has the property of enable drag/drop, but I want to display the marble graphically. I thought I could use a `QLabel` and somehow use the following code:

```
class DragMarble(QLabel):
    def dragenable(self):
        self.setDragEnabled(True)

class PlaceToDrop(QLabel):
    def dropenable(self):
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)
```

However, python gives me the following error message:

> 'QLabel' object has no attribute 'setDragEnabled'

Dees anybody have a better idea to accomplish that task?